# pychromecast unable to find any devices

Tags: python, python-3.x, chromecast

I am trying to write a script that is able to cast a video to chromecast device using python.
I am using `pychromecast` package. However when I run the command `pychromecast.get_chromecasts()` I get an empty list. However If I try to cast using other tools, like chrome browser or vlc media player, I was able to find devices to cast to.

In addition I tried to run this line of code on another computer and I was able to find the chromecast device I wanted.
I use windows 10 on both computers.

What can cause this? is there a firewall setting I should disable